# Google Sheet - COUNTIF - with multiple columns and criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to construct a COUNTIF function to pull out the number of "4" values of the "Status" column but considering only if the corresponding "gender" value is "1". From the image below you would expect to retrieve a total of 2.

Hope someone can help me with this. Thank you

[image: example table]

Comment: In the image there are not values of 2 in gender column where status value is 1. How you can get total = 2?

Comment: COUNTIFS is the function you want.

Comment: @basic Well.... :/

Comment: @basic I meant status  value "4" and gender value "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *Irene Liberali* said use [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550):

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,4,C:C,1)
```

[image]